# What is the connection between health, exercise, and meditation?

Tags: mental-health, exercise, meditation

I have heard that health, exercise and meditation have a connection. How do these three factors interact towards having a better or more relaxing life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the mental benefits of meditation, there is some evidence for organic/physical benefits as well.

Dean Ornish, [the well known cardiologist who helped former U.S. President Clinton with his diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean_Ornish) - and the creator of the only FDA approved prescribed and reimbursed diet for cardiac disease, also has done studies on meditation and health.

He found that [telomeres, the ends of chromosomes that slowly get eroded away with aging, actually regrow with meditation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24051140). He reported these findings at the [Exponential Medicine Conference in San Diego](https://exponential.singularityu.org/medicine/) in 2014.

[Telomere shortening is believed to be one of the foundational causes of aging.](https://www.tasciences.com/what-is-a-telomere/)

It is unclear whether his work has been duplicated elsewhere, but it is a striking and considered highly significant physical finding with implications for health and longevity. It is one of the few actual cellular changes that have been found related to meditation.

Comment: Supporting references are required here.

Comment: Can you explain it in more depth?

Comment: @ErandaPeiris You might want to slow down before accepting an answer. This answer doesn't meet site standards and is likely to be deleted unless the author adds supporting references.

Comment: You should clarify that the paper on regrowing telomeres is not specifically on meditation, but lifestyle change in general. The abstract only mentions changes to _diet, activity, stress management, and social support_. Do you have access to the full text to verify that this actually included meditation?